# Is there anything missing from the original sentence?

Tags: meaning

> All the kings and queens of the day were invited to the wedding feast, as well as all the immortal ones who lived on Mount Olympus – all that is, except for one, for no invitation was sent to Eris, the goddess of strife. **Now strife is when people argue, and it was generally thought a bad idea to invite strife to a wedding party, in case she caused the happy couple to quarrel**

i think this sentence must be this way: Now strife is when people argue, and it was generally thought being a bad idea to invite strife to a wedding party, in case she caused the happy couple to quarrel.

Comment: Your version is not idiomatic. It's perfectly acceptable to say 'It was thought a bad idea to...' , meaning 'it was thought that it was a bad idea'.

Comment: "it was thought to be..." would be fine, but not "it was thought being...". Nothing wrong with "it was thought a bad idea.. ", though.